# reinitialize code first created tables, but leave existed tables data on place with entity framework 6

Tags: sql-server, database, entity-framework, code-first, entity-framework-migrations

Let's say I have 10 entites. 8 of them completelly new and build with EF Code-first aproach. So before I was using `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges` initialization strategy and that's worked perfect for me.

But now I have 2 entites which build from database based on some 3rd party data, and I need this data all the time, I can't allow EF to drop this tables even if model chnages. I need something more inteligent there.

Which is correct approach in that case?

---

In short, I want something quite similar. I just need DbInitializer behavior, but per table basis, instead of per Database. I wan't Code-first entities work the same as before, regerating and all that stuff. But add only something custom for this specific 2 DB based entities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [EF Code First Migrations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx)

First, you need to run the `Enable-Migrations` command in Package Manager Console. This command will add a Migrations folder to our project. This new folder contains the `Configuration` class that allows you to configure how Migrations behaves for your context.

Now, after that,If you followed the **required** steps, you can run "update database" from the "Package Manager Console" and add the eight new tables to your DB:

Example:

1. Make the changes in your model (add the eight new entities)
2. From the *Package Manager Console*: Run **Add-Migration** *[Migration Name]*
3. Make any neccessary changes to the generated code (this is optional).
4. From the *Package Manager Console*: Run **Update-Database**

If you don't change or remove any property related to your existing entities, you should not loose the data that you already have in DB.

### Update

To achieve what you want you can use [Automated Migration](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/automated-migration-in-code-first.aspx). This way when you run your application, you will always get your database in the latest version because EF will do implicit migration every time it is needed - in the purest version you never need to do anything more than enabling automatic migrations.

First, you need to set the database initializer in the context class with the new db initialization strategy `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion` as shown below:

```
   public class YourContext: DbContext 
   {
        public YourContext(): base("DefaultConnectionString") 
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<YourContext, YourProject.Migrations.Configuration>("DefaultConnectionString"));    
        }
   }
```

Later,  in the constructor of the `Configuration` class you have to enable automatic migrations:

```
  public Configuration()
  {
    AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
  }
```

Now, if you are working with an existing database, before add your new eight entities, you need to do this first:

1. Run the `Add-Migration InitialCreate –IgnoreChanges` command in
   Package Manager Console. This creates an empty migration with the
   current model as a snapshot.
2. Run the `Update-Database` command in Package Manager Console. This
   will apply the InitialCreate migration to the database. Since the
   actual migration doesn’t contain any changes, it will simply add a
   row to the __MigrationsHistory table indicating that this migration
   has already been applied.

After that, you can apply the changes that you want to your model (adding, for example, the new eight entities), and when you execute your app again, EF will do the migrations for you.

In case that you are going to change
    someting that provoke some inconsistency regarding to your database
    schema that it could end in data loss, an exception will be throw.
    If this exception is not thrown, you don't have to worry about loss
    your data, it will remain intact in your DB.

As an aditional information,  if you don't mind loose your data (which I think this is not your escenerario, but is useful to know anyway) you can set in `true` the `AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed` property  (its default value is `false`), and no exception will be thrown in case you are going to loose some data in your DB in the execution of a migration.

```
public Configuration()
{
    AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
    AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed=true;
}
```

Comment: But this approach seems to have quite a lot of limitation and it's very manual. We need to edit Migration each time by hand, need to run it manually, so extending something start looks like a serious overhead, and if I still develop activelly, I need to waste a lot of time fore that. Maybe there is something more automated?

Comment: Hello @silent_coder, I have updated my aswer, check the Update section

Comment: Ok, But what else if make a small change in Code first model 1. Than I need to regenerate Migration code, once again need to remove all parts which relate to DB based entities. This doesn't seems very automotive.

Comment: If you apply tha last configuration that I suggest you, you don't need to worry in migrate your code, EF will do the job for you in case you change your model

Comment: Ok. I did like you say. But now I have error throwing: {"There is already an object named 'TableWhichExistInDB' in the database."}

Comment: How did you create the first two entities that represent existing tables, by yourself or using some tool like [EF Power Tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d). If you create those classes by yourself, you need to  match the names between your entities (and properties) and  tables (and columns) in your database. To do that, you can use the `Table` and `Column` attributes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71285/discussion-between-silent-coder-and-octavioccl).